# Where did this guy's body go?

Tags: breaking-bad

In the *Breaking Bad* episode "...And the bag's in the river" (episode 3 of the first season):

> Walt kills Krazy 8

But we're not shown what happens to the body? Did Walt use the acid trick again?

Comment: actually, yes, he did

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to this [source](http://breakingbad.wikia.com/wiki/Domingo_Molina),

> It is then heavily implied by Jesse that he was dissolved in hydrofluoric acid like his cousin Emilio.

Jesse says in Season 1 Episode 7:

> "**I got two dudes that turned into raspberry slushie then flushed down my toilet. I can't even take a proper dump in there. I mean, the whole damn house has got to be haunted by now."**

I think this is a pretty clear indication that the acid trick was used with Krazy 8 and his remains were flushed down the toilet.

Comment: When did Jesse imply this?

Comment: Updated Answer.